# How to use "sortBy" in a p:dataTable with HashSet collection

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

> UPDATED

I have the following dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable id="shipOwnerCompanyHistoriesTable" widgetVar="shipOwnerCompanyHistoriesTable" var="entry" value="#{shipRegisterView.ship.shipOwnerCompanyHistories}" rowKey="#{entry}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{shipRegisterView.selectedShipOwnerCompanyHistory}" 
                 styleClass="margin-bottom-10" paginator="true" rows="5"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10" emptyMessage="Δεν βρέθηκαν εγγραφές.">
                 
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form" listener="#{shipRegisterView.selectShipOwnerCompanyHistory}" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@form" listener="#{shipRegisterView.unselectShipOwnerCompanyHistory}" />

                <p:column headerText="Πλοιοκτησία">
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.company.brandNameGreek} / #{entry.company.brandNameLatin}"/>
                </p:column>
                                    
                <p:column headerText="Από" sortBy="#{entry.fromDate}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.fromDate}">
                       <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Έως" sortBy="#{entry.toDate}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.toDate}">
                       <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                
                <p:column headerText="Ποσοστό" sortBy="#{entry.percentage}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.percentage}%"/>
                </p:column>
                
                <p:column headerText="Σημειώσεις">
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.comments}" rendered="#{entry.comments != null and not empty entry.comments}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="-" rendered="#{entry.comments == null or empty entry.comments}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

With the value being taken from the follwoing view class like so:

```
public ShipRegisterView() {
    newFlagHistory = new ShipFlagHistory();
    lossState = "";
    growlId = "shipMessages";
    ship = new Ship();
    ship.setLossState("Normal");
    shipList = new ArrayList<Ship>();
    newEncumbrance = new ShipEncumbrance();
    newFek = new ShipFek();
    newShipEngine = new ShipEngine();
    newShipRenameHistory = new ShipRenameHistory();
    newTransferHistory = new ShipTransferHistory();
    newShipOwnerCompanyHistory = new ShipOwnerCompanyHistory();
    newShipOwnerNaturalPersonHistory = new ShipOwnerNaturalPersonHistory();
    newShipAdminCompanyHistory = new ShipAdminCompanyHistory();
    newShipUtilizationCompanyHistory = new ShipUtilizationCompanyHistory();
    newShipOwnerCompanyHistory.setCompany(new Company());
    newShipOwnerNaturalPersonHistory.setNaturalPerson(new NaturalPerson());
    newShipAdminCompanyHistory.setCompany(new Company());
    newShipUtilizationCompanyHistory.setCompany(new Company());
    newConditionHistory = new ShipConditionHistory();
    newRecreationalLicense = new RecreationalLicense();
    newRecreationalLicense.setAdminClassAct(new AdminClassAct());
    newRecreationalLicense.setAdminDeclassAct(new AdminDeclassAct());
    searchInspectionsList = new ArrayList<Inspection>();
    searchCertificatesList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
    searchRosCertificatesList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
    searchAffirmationsList = new ArrayList<Affirmation>();
    
    newNaturalPerson = new NaturalPerson();
    newNaturalPerson.setAddress(new Address());
    searchNaturalPerson = new NaturalPerson();
    
    harboursForShipsForDNPUser = new ArrayList<Harbour>();

    fines = new ArrayList<Fine>();
    complaints = new ArrayList<Complaint>();
    completedRoutes = new ArrayList<CompletedRoute>();

    searchOwnerCompany = new SearchCompany();
    searchOwnerNaturalPerson = new SearchNaturalPerson();
    searchAdminCompany = new SearchCompany();
    searchUtilizationCompany = new SearchCompany();

    ship.setShipEngines(new HashSet<ShipEngine>());
    ship.setShipAdminCompanyHistories(new HashSet<ShipAdminCompanyHistory>());
    ship.setShipOwnerCompanyHistories(new HashSet<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>());
    ship.setShipOwnerNaturalPersonHistories(new HashSet<ShipOwnerNaturalPersonHistory>());
    ship.setShipUtilizationCompanyHistories(new HashSet<ShipUtilizationCompanyHistory>());
    ship.setShipEncumbrances(new HashSet<ShipEncumbrance>());
    ship.setShipConditionHistories(new ArrayList<ShipConditionHistory>());
    ship.setShipFeks(new HashSet<ShipFek>());
    ship.setDocuments(new HashSet<AccompanyingFile>());
    ship.setShipPhotos(new HashSet<ShipPhoto>());
    ship.setShipFlagHistories(new HashSet<ShipFlagHistory>());
    ship.setRecreationalLicenses(new HashSet<RecreationalLicense>());
    ship.setShipTransferHistories(new HashSet<ShipTransferHistory>());
    ship.setLossTheftDecisions(new HashSet<LossTheftDecision>());
    ship.setShipRenameHistories(new HashSet<ShipRenameHistory>());
    
    List<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory> list = new ArrayList<>(shipOwnerCompanyHistories);
    
};
```

The thing i am trying to do is to sort the columns of the table using the `sortBy` attribute of primefaces. When i press the column, i get the following error on the webpage:
[image]

And on my tomcat:

> ERROR (com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.internal.ExceptionHandlerAjaxImpl.java:71).handle - Data type should be java.util.List or javax.faces.model.ListDataModel instance to be sortable.

Now, i understand that it has to be a list in order to work, but is there a way where i can sort the table? Hibernate mapping is a `set` too:

```
<set name="shipOwnerCompanyHistories" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
        <key column="shipId" on-delete="cascade"/>
        <one-to-many class="gr.yptp.hcg.sr.Model.ShipOwnerCompanyHistory"/>
    </set>
```

Let me know. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: How about `new ArrayList<>(yourHashSet)`?

Comment: Like that? `new ArrayList<>(HashSet<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>());` 
I'm getting an error: Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token.
It refers to the parenthesis after `<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>`

Comment: No. `List<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory> list = new ArrayList<>(shipOwnerCompanyHistories);`

Comment: So, I am writing this line under the one I posted in my view class, inside the `ShipRegisterView` method, but it doesn't seem to work, as it produces an error. Sorry for that, I am new to jsf and honestly sometimes I'm at a loss.

Comment: 'an error' ???? Hard to help with that and please edit the question with an update and add the real code there that you changed. Then we can see what you actually have

Comment: @Kukeltje Edited the question.

Comment: So you have the same error? The java code you have after the edit  is very weird. Are you new to java too?

Comment: Error is the same yes, it can't find `shipOwnerCompanyHistories` which I get, it's just that I can't seem to understand what I should put inside the parenthesis in `new ArrayList<>()`. The code was already written... Right now I'm resolving bugs and implementing new functionality where it is needed. I am a beginner developer also.

Comment: @Kukeltje Added the whole method of the my view class, maybe it will help.

Comment: 1: It is not about whole methods... 2: To me seems you are indeed relatively new  (web)development (not a problem, just notice this due to the code weird assignment to variables and not using them... hmmm). 3: Did not not occur to you that you have a problem with the `shipOwnerCompanyHistories` field and the suggested code change is nowhere assigned to this field?  so do `ship.setShipOwnerCompanyHistories(new ArrayList(new HashSet<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>()));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ship.setShipOwnerCompanyHistories(new HashSet<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>());
```

and further on

```
List<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory> list = new ArrayList<>(shipOwnerCompanyHistories);
```

(where the list variable is nowhere used anymore, doesn't it have a yellow squirreled lin under it in your IDE?)

Do

```
 ship.setShipOwnerCompanyHistories(new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>()));
```

or just

```
 ship.setShipOwnerCompanyHistories(new ArrayList<ShipOwnerCompanyHistory>());
```

or you you retrieved the `shipOwnerCompanyHistories` variable (assuming it is a HashSet from the database, do

```
 ship.setShipOwnerCompanyHistories(new ArrayList<>(shipOwnerCompanyHistories));
```

Comment: I'll do whatever I can to fix it... Thank you very much for your time and your help. I know I have a lot to learn. If I get it to work, I'll mark the answer.